# Can't find python script of different ros package in Pycharm

Tags: ros, setup.py, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I was following [this](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html) guide to be able to access a python script from one ros package in another one. I am trying to execute the following script in Pycharm:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from robot_control.moveclass import MoveClass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node("test")
    mc = MoveClass()
    mc.move_cart_rel((0.0, 0.0, -0.1, 0, 0, 0))
```

Executing the script works fine and pycharm is able to resolve the rospy import, but can **Not** resolve `from robot_control.moveclass import MoveClass`.

I also followed [this guide](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#PyCharm_.28community_edition.29) to get Pycharm running for ROS.
I really dont know, what I did wrong. This is the content of my `setup.py` file:

```
## ! DO NOT MANUALLY INVOKE THIS setup.py, USE CATKIN INSTEAD

from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

# fetch values from package.xml
setup_args = generate_distutils_setup(
    packages=['robot_control'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
)
setup(**setup_args)
```

The `setup.py` file is located in the catkin package `robot_control` and the `__init__.py` and `moveclass.py` files are located relative to that catkin package in `src/robot_control`.

How am I able to get Pycharm to resolve my script, which I wanna use in multiple other packages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286242/can%27t-find-python-script-of-different-ros-package-in-pycharm/) by [nmelchert](https://answers.ros.org/users/29154/nmelchert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2018-03-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**See the better solution on EDIT and EDIT2**

Finally "solved" ! I'm not sure if this is a limitation of catkin or if it's the intended behavior. Here's what I observed:

- Under *External Libraries* in pycharm, you can find the libraries that the software can find, and it gets the ROS libraries via PYTHONPATH.
- If you find and check under your **robot_control** library, you will see that only the `__init__.py` file (and possibly messages, services) are listed, but not the modules of your package. This is why pycharm can't find the files - catkin is not **installing** them

One way of solving:

1. Change your catkin build configuration to also install (if using **catkin-python-tools**), or perform catkin_make install for the packages you want to import. Now, if you search under the `install` space, you will notice that your modules are actually there as well.
2. Add `install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` to your PYTHONPATH. To do this, either `source install/setup.bash` before running pycharm, or add them manually in *Settings->Project->Project Interpreter->Gear->Show All->(Last Icon, it's a dir tree)*

Now pycharm will find your modules. You may also want to edit the `__init__.py` file of your modules, see here a good reference: http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html

---

**EDIT**

Same issue reported [here](https://github.com/team-vigir/flexbe_behavior_engine/issues/34). It is Pycharm's fault of not parsing catkin's `__init__.py` file to go find the available modules. The solution is provided in that link, which for me is better than my previous solution, but very tedious.

**EDIT2**

Solution pasted (adapted) here in case it gets lost:

1. Open PyCharm's settings
2. Open your project on the left of the settings window
3. Open Project Structure
4. Select your project
5. Click on Add Content Root
6. Add the root of your package, where CMakeLists is located
7. Click on OK, the package will now show up on the Project Tree view on the left
8. On the Project view, find the top-most *src* directory of the module you want to add, Right-Click -> Mark Directory As -> Source Root

---

Originally posted by [dotcom](https://answers.ros.org/users/19883/dotcom/) with karma: 120 on 2018-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nmelchert](https://answers.ros.org/users/29154/nmelchert/) on 2018-03-29**:
Thanks for your answer.

I also prefer the solution you mentioned [here](https://github.com/team-vigir/flexbe_behavior_engine/issues/34). It worked perfectly for me.

Thanks for your help.